SqlPlus works, but SqlDeveloper gives ORA-12505 TNS listener error when making a connection
I've installed Oracle 19c Enterprise on a Windows Server 2019. After installing, I used SQL Plus to connect as "SYS as SYSDBA" account successfully, and made queries etc.
However, when trying to connect via Sql Developer, I get the following error:
Status : Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

In the /network/admin folder, I already had the listener.ora and sqlnet.ora files.
I created the tnsnames.ora file with the following config:
TEST_DB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1522))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = TEST)
    )
  )

My listener.ora file looks like this:
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\Users\testUser\Downloads\WINDOWS.X64_193000_db_home\NETWORK\ADMIN\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = XE

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\Users\testUser\Downloads\WINDOWS.X64_193000_db_home)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\Users\testUser\Downloads\WINDOWS.X64_193000_db_home\bin\oraclr19.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1522))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1522))
    )
  )


Note, the DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = XE line I added manually when seeking help online. The rest is as it came I believe.
I had some issues restarting some of the Oracle services after editing the files, but a server restart later, they're all running.
I checked lsnrctl status and start in cmd:
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1522)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Start Date                12-JUL-2024 16:04:43
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 5 min. 53 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   C:\Users\testUser\Downloads\WINDOWS.X64_193000_db_home\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\Oracle19c\diag\tnslsnr\V-LABAPPDB2\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1522)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1522ipc)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully

C:\Windows\system32>lsnrctl start

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on 12-JUL-2024 16:11:12

Copyright (c) 1991, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

TNS-01106: Listener using listener name LISTENER has already been started

And finally, I've tried a bunch of combinations on Sql Developer connection.
The username, I've tried between: "sys as sysdba", "sys" with the Role as SYSDBA. I doubt it's a user/id issue as the Test isn't getting to that point
Hostname: localhost (tried the dedicated IP too)
Port: 1522
SID: TEST (though I tried TEST_DB too)
tnsping test_db gives:
Used parameter files:
C:\Users\testUser\Downloads\WINDOWS.X64_193000_db_home\network\admin\sqlnet.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1522))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = LCM)))
OK (0 msec)

I thought it should be tnsping localhost 1522 but that doesn't work. And on just tnsping localhost it tries default port 1521.
Not sure where to go from here....

This question has already been answered N times here... in short SQL*Plus uses OS authentication not SQLDeveloper: database parameter REMOTE_LOGIN_PASSWORDFILE must be set to exclusive and the password file must exits (in $ORACLE_HOME/dbs/orapw), create one - with orapwd  - if not.

This is a kinda advanced topic that you shouldn't normally need to get into on a fresh install... but your lsnrctl output should show a Service named TEST, and it doesn't - it just shows the CLRExtProc service. This means that the db instance isn't registered with the Listener, so only local OS authentication will work.
When it's working lsnrctl status will show a line like:
Services Summary...
  Service "TEST" has 1 instance(s).
  [...]

Weirdly your TNSPING is connecting to a service named LCM, which I don't see in your Listener output.
There's two ways to solve this - static and dynamic registration.
For static registration, add a SID_DESC entry to your SID_LIST in listener.ora:
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\Users\testUser\Downloads\WINDOWS.X64_193000_db_home)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\Users\testUser\Downloads\WINDOWS.X64_193000_db_home\bin\oraclr19.dll")
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = TEST)
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = TEST)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\Users\testUser\Downloads\WINDOWS.X64_193000_db_home)
    )
  )

For dynamic registration, this normally happens automatically, but you can connect to your db as sysdba, and run alter system register; to tell the instance to try registering itself.
